# %eax does not decrement? (ATT Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, att

I am new to AT&T assembly and I am learning to use the decrement operator, `decl` to create a program that prints `Hello world!` 5 times.

Here's the code:

```
.data

hello:
    .ascii  "Hello world!"

   .text
loop:
    decl    %eax
    leaq    hello(%rip), %rdi
    call    _puts
    jnz     loop
    leave
    ret

.globl _main
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    movl    $5, %eax
    jmp     loop

    movl    $0, %eax

    leave
    ret
```

However, the program prints `Hello world!` indefinitely though it compiles with no errors. What's wrong?

**EDIT**

After the suggestions to:

1. Change from `%eax` to `%rax`
2. Add `push` and `pop`
3. Reorder the `decq` call
4. `call` `loop` instead of `jmp`

Here is the resulting code:

```
.data

hello:
    .asciz  "Hello world!"

   .text
loop:
    leaq    hello(%rip), %rdi
    pushq   %rax
    call    _puts
    popq    %rax
    decq    %rax
    jnz     loop

.globl _main
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    movq    $5, %rax
    call    loop

    movq    $0, %rax

    leave
    ret
```

Comment: eax is not preserved by `call _puts` as per usual calling convention. You can surround your `call` with `push eax` and `pop eax`. Also you should use `.asciz` or `.string` to make your string zero terminated.

Comment: @Jester
ok, so here is the new one(# for \n):
    <snip>#   
    pushl %eax#   
    call _puts#   
    popl %eax#   
    </snip>#   
But it returns an error:
    hello.s:45:9: error: instruction requires: Not 64-bit mode
            push %eax
            ^
    hello.s:47:9: error: instruction requires: Not 64-bit mode
            pop %eax
            ^

Comment: Oh sorry, it's 64 bit. Then use `%rax`.

Comment: Now, after compilation, it returns `Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: @MoonCheesez: I'm a little bit amazed at the underscores in `_main` and `_puts`. With what assembler and linker on what operating system do you build the executable?

Comment: @rkhb I am building the executable on Mac OSX Yosemite

Comment: In your second snippet you have to reinsert the first `leave` and `ret`. You used a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and this is the exit of the program.

Comment: @rkhb, yes, this solved the problem. Please post an answer below.

Comment: I made a mistake. You used a tail call in the **first** snippet. In the second snippet is a normal call. That requires nevertheless a `ret`, but in this case no `leave`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As contributed by @Fifoernik and @Jester:

1. Change from `%eax` to `%rax`
2. Add `push` and `pop`
3. Reorder the `decq` call

As contributed by @rhkb, the last piece of the puzzle:

4. Insert `leave` and `ret` into the last part of `loop`

Altogether:

```
.data

hello:
    .asciz  "Hello world!"

    .text
loop:
    leaq    hello(%rip), %rdi
    pushq   %rax
    call    _puts
    popq    %rax
    decq    %rax
    jnz     loop
    movq    $0, %rax
    leave
    ret

.globl _main
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    movq    $5, %rax
    jmp     loop
```

Comment: In __this__ solution it would be more appropriate to use `jmp loop`. In the solution I gave in response to your original question the use of `call loop` was the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you:

- In 64-bit code use %rax in stead of %eax.
- You mustn't expect your `call    _puts` to preserve %rax. So `push` and `pop` it.
- You mustn't expect your `call    _puts` to preserve the flags. So put the `decq %rax` right before `jnz loop`.

Here's the loop:

```
loop:
  leaq    hello(%rip), %rdi
  pushq   %rax
  call    _puts
  popq    %rax
  decq    %rax
  jnz     loop
  RET
```

Adding the suggestion to `call loop`:

```
.globl _main
_main:
  pushq   %rbp
  movq    %rsp, %rbp
  movl    $5, %rax
  CALL    loop
  movl    $0, %rax
  leave
  ret
```

Comment: Same as @Jester in the comments, after changing all these I receive a `Segmentation fault: 11` I will include the edited code above.

Comment: Why did you dismiss your program exit? Why don't you `call loop`?

Comment: edited above. Now no error is given but the `Hello world!` still prints indefinitely.

Comment: Regarding push and pop, the stack need stack needs to be 16-byte aligned in 64-bit mode when making function calls